# How to add number of days to exact date format

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP how i can do this

```
$today = date("m/d/y"); // showing today
```

Output `11/18/13` will be saved in mysql as `start date`

Okay so if i like to add to this `start date` 30 days ... 60 days ... 90 days or any number of days to be add to `$today` and results be still in format `m/d/y`

**Example** may explain more what i mean

```
$today = date("m/d/y"); // 11/18/13
```

then add 10 days so `$expired` should be `$today + 10`; in days and results should be `11/28/13`

~ thanks

Comment: Have you search how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$today = date("m/d/y");
echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($today. ' +10 day'));
```

Out put will be `11/28/13` as you desiring.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime::add()](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.add.php) (PHP 5.3)

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: My server using php version lower thank 5.3 but will keep it into my mind thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this should work for you

```
<?php
$Date = date("m/d/y");
echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($Date. ' + 10 days'));

?>
```